# Stack Overflow logo not visible on "site rooms" button in chat

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, logo

Being orange logo on orange button, the logo is not really visible in chat rooms on stackexchange.com domain having Stack Overflow as their parent site: ([sample room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57773/calvbot-sandbox))

> [image: site rooms logo not visible]

Can this please be fixed, e.g. by adding a white background?

> [image: site rooms button with white background for logo]

Comment: Agree on that it needs fixing, but the white background is awful ... sorry.

Comment: @rene well, if you have better idea...

Comment: @Shadow stick to chat.SO and then you don't have to worry about it? :p

Comment: **Blue** background will be better contrast. 0)

Comment: ... or just change the logo...

Comment: Actually, I think we do not really need to logo. I can't see how it would help and the issue is propably the same for rooms for Ask Ubuntu (and maybe other sites).

Comment: That white square looks like a cut and paste job in MS Paint.

Comment: The logo is (slightly) visible when you hover over it. This is by-design maybe, but the color scheme definitely needs a change.

Comment: @AlexL are you doubting Shadow's skill in paint?

Comment: @Braiam No, he is pretty good, but definitely has a room to improve. You see, there are 3 pixels on top and 1 on the bottom of icon. Icon should have been 1 pixel higher up. Experienced MS Paint professional would have spot that.

Comment: @AlexL no paint was used (except from cropping the screenshot), I [added white background using Chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neLXt.png). So what you found is bug with SO code itself. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, I just checked. Indeed, it's as simple as `background: white;` on `<img>` tag. That should take 6-8 month.

Comment: @AlexL lol... well looking again, it's indeed not really elegant, just my very rough attempt to make it better. What you suggested in the answer is better, though will take much longer since it requires actual designer to do it, and they're busy making new designs for graduated sites.

Answer (score 14):

Obviously just get rid of the logo...

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something along these lines? Orange background, grey stack holder (maybe a little lighter grey then the one I used), white overflow:

[image]

Comment: Or just remove the icon.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Post that as an answer and let's see which one of our answers will get more upvotes.

Comment: Nah, that's okay.

Comment: @AlexL someone else did it.. lol

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, I already downvoted that :)